# how to make UI update appear before end of Jquery .click function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button which is used to make some processing and Ajax calls, so I did that in Jquery `.click()` and it works fine but when I try to make loading spinner the loading spinner doesn't appear before the end of the ajax and .click() code.

So I want to start the spinner in the start of `.click()`and hide on ajax success, how to do that?

Like:

```
    $("#ConfirmBTN").click(function () {

    $("#confirmBody").LoadingOverlay("show");
    ... some code
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                url: url,
                data: "jsonData=" + jsonData,
                success: function (returnPayload) {
                ..
                    $("#confirmBody").LoadingOverlay("hide");
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    $("#confirmBody").LoadingOverlay("hide");
                },
                processData: false,
                async: false
            });

    }
```

Comment: Get rid of the synchronous ajax and your problem will go away.  If you think you have reasons for using synchronous ajax, then you just need to learn how to code with async ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `async: false`. Then your click function will return to the browser's main event loop, and it will update the display.

Move any code that depends on the AJAX response into the `success:` function.